# Can I call more than one fields from inline table on Mondrian?

Tags: mdx, mondrian

Is it possible to call two fields from one dimension but every filed have their own key?
For example I've fact table that have two foreign key (`agestart` and `ageend`).
And I have inline table that declare value of `agestart` and `ageend`.

I have try to declare each field on different dimension and call it like this.

```
select 
  {[dimagestart].[agestart].members}*
  {[dimageend].[ageend.members} on columns
from cube1
```

but the result is look like

```
|agestart   |
|18         |
|ageend     |
|20|25|30|35|
```

I want the result is look like

```
|agestart   |
|18-20|21-25|
```

Any idea?
Every help will be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for what I want. I'm just add where condition on mdx and look like this.

```
select 
  {[dimagestart].[agestart].members}*
  {[dimageend].[ageend.members} on columns
from cube1
where 
   [dimageend].[ageend]
```